# finding middle of linked list using fast/slow ptrs, running into nullptr error when I should not be (fast.next.next check)

Tags: java, linked-list

Here's my code to find the middle of the linked list:

```
public ListNode findMiddleNode(ListNode head) {
    if(head == null){return null;}
    if(head.next == null){return head;}
    ListNode slow = head;
    ListNode fast = head;
    while(fast != null && fast.next.next != null){
        slow = slow.next;
        fast = fast.next.next;
    }
    return slow;

}
```

In the case of 1->2->3->4->5, the final iteration of this should be:

```
1->2->3->4->5
      s
            f
```

My loop should end right here. fast.next.next is null and does not exist. However, I get a console nullptr error instead of the answer '3'. My guess is somehow I'm going outside the list.

Can anyone reason a guess why this is happening?

Edit: Looks like if I add the condition "fast.next" in my while loop, it works. No clue why.

Edit 2: Is "fast.next.next", when fast is at the end of my list at 5, giving me some kind of junk value that isn't null? Just a guess.

Edit 3: Here is my full results output: https://ibb.co/XpNbFWh , on firecode.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
    while(fast != null && fast.next.next != null){
```

The above line of code checks `fast.next.next` without checking `fast.next`.

Since `fast.next` can be null, `fast.next.next` can throw `NullPointerException` in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your code inside the while and the condition have logic mistakes.
Try this, I tried it on paper and it seems to work fine:

```
    while(fast != null && fast.next != null){
        slow = slow.next;
        if (fast.next != null)
        {
          fast = fast.next;
          if (fast.next!=null)
             fast = fast.next;
        }
    }
```

I guess the code can be simplified, but well, as the another user said, your mistake is on the line **fast.next.next**.
For that reason inside the while I added the condition **fast.next != null**
to avoid the NullPointerException.
You should verify on a paper the way is working the code inside the while loop and its conditions